# Can't get v-img to center inside v-flex

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify and I'm trying to build a login screen. I can't get v-img to center inside of v-flex. I've tried a lot of things, but am really stuck. I'm referring to the Vue logo in the right v-flex.

[image]

I can't get the snippet to show exactly as the image above, but I don't think it really matters as the Vue logo isn't centered either in the snippet. If there is a better way to create the setup as shown in the image I would really like to know. As I said, i'm new to this and still learning.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
      showPassword:false
    }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.2/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <v-app style="
    background-color: #011c40;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,  #011c40 50%,  rgb(26, 65, 115) 100%);
    background-size: cover;
  ">
    <v-main>
       <v-container  class="fill-height"
               fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-row
                justify="center"
        >
          <v-card tile>
            <v-layout align-center>
              <v-flex xs6 class="hidden-sm-and-down">
                <v-img src="http://www.dpereira.nl/Er/img/banner.png" width="500px"></v-img>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex class="pa-10 pb-8 text-center">
                <v-img class="" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png" width="100px"></v-img>
                <v-card-text class="pb-0">
                  <v-form>
                    <v-text-field
                            label="Gebruikersnaam"/>
                    <v-text-field
                            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                            label="Wachtwoord"
                            :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                            @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                    />
                    <v-checkbox dense label="Onthoud mij"></v-checkbox>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
               <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn height="50px" tile ripple depressed block color="secondary">Inloggen</v-btn>
               </v-card-actions>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <div class="pt-3">
                  <div class="d-block caption text-center"><a href="">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></div>
                  <div class="d-block caption text-center">Nog geen account? Meld u <a href="">hier</a> aan.</div>
                </div>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you are using vuetify 2 not vuetify 1, so `v-flex` and `v-layout` is not available, you can use flex classes on simple `div`s or use `v-row` and `v-col` instead if you want to use grid. See here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have added `mx-auto` class on `v-img`, now it's working as intended.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
      showPassword:false
    }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.2/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <v-app style="
    background-color: #011c40;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,  #011c40 50%,  rgb(26, 65, 115) 100%);
    background-size: cover;
  ">
    <v-main>
       <v-container  class="fill-height"
               fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-row
                justify="center"
        >
          <v-card tile>
            <v-layout align-center>
              <v-flex xs6 class="hidden-sm-and-down">
                <v-img src="http://www.dpereira.nl/Er/img/banner.png" width="500px"></v-img>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex class="pa-10 pb-8 text-center">
                  <v-img class="mx-auto" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png" width="100px"></v-img>
                <v-card-text class="pb-0">
                  <v-form>
                    <v-text-field
                            label="Gebruikersnaam"/>
                    <v-text-field
                            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                            label="Wachtwoord"
                            :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                            @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                    />
                    <v-checkbox dense label="Onthoud mij"></v-checkbox>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
               <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn height="50px" tile ripple depressed block color="secondary">Inloggen</v-btn>
               </v-card-actions>
                <v-divider></v-divider>
                <div class="pt-3">
                  <div class="d-block caption text-center"><a href="">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a></div>
                  <div class="d-block caption text-center">Nog geen account? Meld u <a href="">hier</a> aan.</div>
                </div>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'm using Vuetify 2.3.1. Your code shows one v-card and now the images are all centered inside the v-card on top of each other. What I'm looking for is something like the image in my question. I've updated the image (see above) to better reflect what I'm looking for. So I want two cards next to each other. The left card holds the image with the hands (vertically centered) and the right card holds the form. In the right card I can't get the Vue logo to horizontally center (so above the form). I've tried it with just v-col, but didn't manage to get it right.

Comment: @Diego I have updated my answer. Hope so you will get it! Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use flex box to center the content (adjusting the container height for vertical alignment)

```
<v-container fluid>
  <v-layout justify-center align-center>
    <v-flex shrink>
      <div>your content</div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Comment: I had to add fill-height for the v-container.